# Connect PHP with Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I've made 2 websites on heroku. One is my chat application built with node.js and second is my PHP built website. i want to integrate the node.js chat in my site. how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on your service-oriented architecture!  You can integrate them with web requests; http lets you make what in effect are cross-host function calls.  Php can call the node service with the curl_* functions.